# angular scroll sideways on button click

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a div containing some cards.
Sometimes there are more cards than the window can show.
In that case I want the to have a left and right buttons to scroll one card left/right when clicked.
I do not want to show a horizontal scroll bar.

```
<div class=lane>
    <span class='arrow-left' (click)="scrollOneCardLeft()">left</span>
    <span class='arrow-right' (click)="scrollOneCardRight()">right</span>
    <div  class=card-cont *ngFor="let card of myCards; let i = index">
       <div class="card"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

```css
.lane {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

span.arrow-left,span.arrow-right{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #555;    
  color:pink;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  height:200px;
}
span.arrow-left{
  left: 0px;
}
span.arrow-right{
  right: 0px;
}
.card-cont {
  margin: 10px;
}
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

How should I implement the scrollOneCardLeft() and scrollOneCardRight() on the Angular component so that on click one item will be scrolled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same issue and, with the help from other posts I ended up those 2 methods.

```
  scrollLeft(el: Element) {
    const animTimeMs = 400;
    const pixelsToMove = 315;
    const stepArray = [0.001, 0.021, 0.136, 0.341, 0.341, 0.136, 0.021, 0.001];
    interval(animTimeMs / 8)
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(value => value < 8),
        tap(value => el.scrollLeft -= (pixelsToMove * stepArray[value])),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  scrollRight(el: Element) {
    const animTimeMs = 400;
    const pixelsToMove = 315;
    const stepArray = [0.001, 0.021, 0.136, 0.341, 0.341, 0.136, 0.021, 0.001];
    interval(animTimeMs / 8)
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(value => value < 8),
        tap(value => el.scrollLeft += (pixelsToMove * stepArray[value])),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

They use reactive operations to gradually change the left position of the scroll.

Maybe try messing with the numbers, this approach fit my need, with a couple tweaks can fit yours.

You can call 'em by the `(click)` event by passing the reference of your list (the container that has horizontal scroll)

```
  <div class="horizontal-scroll" #list>...</div>
  <button (click)="scrollLeft(list)">Left</button>
```

Comment: Forgot to tell in the answer, but the `stepsArray` is a way to mimic ease in and out.

Comment: One of the best solutions so far without implementing ViewChild, helps when you have multiple scrolling divs in a page!

Comment: @João Ghignatti  Is there a way to hide the buttons when on extreme ends?

Comment: You can check if scrollLeft is 0 for left extreme and scrollLeft equals scrollWidth for right extreme.